# Timepicker Style not chaning according to android versions

Tags: android, xml, timepicker

I am developing an android app, where I am using TimePicker. The problem is, the TimePicker Style is not getting updated according to the different versions of android.

The same older version of TimePicker is appearing even in the latest jellyBean phone.
Not sure of what could be the issue.

Please help! Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Value-v11,v14 folders in the package has style.xml with the following code.

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.



    -->
</style>

<style name="myDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Please post your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Specifically the parts with theme(s) and target-sdk.

Comment: check out the link http://txtup.co/XCY9T for my manifest.xml.

Comment: I see you use `Theme.NoTitleBar` for app theme and there are also some activities that use `@style/myDialog` as theme. Just to check if this is really a reason, try to remove these theme changes (to fall back to a default theme).

Comment: Thanks.. i fixed the problem. I applied the Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog
style for the myDialog style.

Comment: Good, it means that `Theam` was a right direction (I was not 100% sure).

Comment: Also, is there a possible way to change the font, color, size etc of the text in timepicker?

Comment: I haven't tried, but I think it should be possible. Check this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme There is a part describing how to use a customized theme.

Comment: Thanks,got solution for that too. We need to make use of the "item" attributes within the style to customize the default styles. <style name="myDialog2" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
       
    </style>

Answer (score 0):

Do you Have a folder in your project directory named values-xhdpi/ values-hdpi ??

Comment: I have these folders, its working fine for normal activities. But, if I make my activity which contains the timepicker as a dialog activity, then the lastest TimePicker style is applied.

Comment: ok from these folders remove the style.xml or just remove the app style from them to overcome the latest android version theme. whats happening is your theme is overridden on latest theme just check if you can find any App/base theme in these folder style.xml file and simple comment them and see the magic
.. i hope thats what you want

Comment: I want the latest timepicker style to come up on latest phones, which is not happening.Even the latest phones are showing the older style itself. Please checkout the question again.

Comment: can you please paste the code of style.xml from values-xhdpi/values-hdpi

Comment: instead this : <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
try this :
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">

Comment: make sure this apptheme is implemmented in menifest under application tag

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. i did try ur above solution, but if i try to add the theme Theme.Holo.Light in my manifest, its throwing an error saying API 11 required, coz my min API level is 9, and target is 17. Any other suggestions.

Comment: Thanks.. i fixed the problem. I applied the Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog
style for the myDialog style.